# What is the method of referencing version control commit tags and hashes in Redmine?

Tags: tags, commit, redmine, message, hash

What is the method of referencing version control commit tags and hashes in Redmine?

ie in commit messages, and in the notes and wikis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting :

- Link to an issue: #124
- Link to a changeset: r758
- Link to a changeset with a non-numeric hash: commit:c6f4d0fd

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using multiple version control repositories per project, you can link to a changeset as well:

```
{project}:commit:{repository}|{revision}
```

So if you have a project named `myproject` with two repositories named `repo1` and `repo2`, you can link to a specific changeset from `repo1` like this:

```
myproject:commit:repo1|8f946151b780
```

*(tested with Mercurial repositories)*